# php inner join more than 2 tables

Tags: php

I have 2 tables one for the login id, username, password and rank and the other one is for account status. I need to join the tables to execute only all the active accounts. Everytime I try my code in phpmyadmin it works fine but in my system it won't work. Is there anything problem with my code? Btw. rank is for account verfication if you are an administartor or student.

```
$sql = "SELECT a.login_id,username,password,rank,b.status FROM login2 as a    INNER JOIN login_stat2 as b ON a.login_id = b.login_id WHERE username     ='".$username."' AND password='".$pass."' AND b.status='ACTIVE'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($row = mysqli_num_rows($result));
session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['login_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_NAME']      = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_RANK']      = $member['rank'];


        if($member['rank']=='administrator'){
        header("location: login_reg.php");
        }

        else if($member['rank']=='student'){
        header("location: student.php");
        }
        else if($member['rank']=='candidate'){
        header("location: candidate.php");
        }

        }else{
        print "Incorrect username or password";

            session_write_close();
```

Comment: Define "won't work". The most obvious thing I see if that a while loop on `mysqli_num_rows` doesn't make sense as on its own that will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: I'd start by telling us exactly what _is_ happening, what _isn't_ happening and _all_ relevant code, not invalid snippets.

Comment: As an aside, your look to be vulnerable to SQL injections (not guaranteed). You should try and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead. You should also `exit();` after sending a location header to the script doesn't continue to run. You also look like you might be storing plain text or simple hashed passwords. I'd suggest looking at, and making use of the [PHP Password API](http://php.net/password) for security.

Comment: My prof. said using PDO will 80% prevent sql injections but I got confused whenever I use it. I'm only student who are lack of knowledge about PHP. I'm just making website for project.

Comment: Well, first off, you're not using PDO. Second, just using PDO doesn't make your SQL less vulnerable to injection than the mysql_* functions if you're concatenating user data directly into queries. As I said, you want to be using prepared statements, which are available in both PDO and MySQLi APIs.

Comment: For now I'm not worrying about that, i just want it to work and if its work then I'll improve my codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT a.login_id,a.username,a.password,a.rank,b.status FROM login2 as a INNER JOIN login_stat2 as b ON a.login_id = b.login_id WHERE a.username     ='".$username."' AND a.password='".$pass."' AND b.status='ACTIVE'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error($con));

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
   echo 'Login success';
} else {
   echo 'invalid username and password';
}
```

The mysqli_num_rows() function returns the number of rows in a result set.

**Updated Code**

```
//create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'demo');

//check connection
if($conn->connect_error) {
  die("connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connection Successful <br>";

$sql = "SELECT a.login_id,a.username,a.password,a.rank,b.status FROM login2 as a INNER JOIN login_stat2 as b ON a.login_id = b.login_id WHERE a.username ='admin' AND a.password='admin' AND b.status='ACTIVE'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    echo "login";
} else {
    print "Incorrect username or password";
}
```

Comment: I used $row for mysqli_fetch and below is if and else condition.And that code I created is for login form.

Comment: if you r using for login then only need to check if($row>0) then true else false

Comment: mysqli_num_rows doesn't fetch an associative array at all, it returns an int.

Comment: sorry it return  number of rows in a result set.

Comment: still wont work. But everytime I place all the login id, username, password and rank together with status it work. But I need to normalize my table, so I split it in to two.

Comment: can you please update your both table so we get the field

Comment: in login-2 table add a reference id of login-1 table

Comment: login 2 has 1 stored in login id, admin in username, admin in password, and administrator in rank while in login_stat2 login id is 1 and status is active.

Comment: status active is in caps?

Comment: everytime I log in it says incorrect username and password.

Comment: Yes the same in my query it is in caps.

Comment: can you please echo the query and check it in phpmyadmin

Comment: I tried to copy my code in phpmyadmin sql it works. It displays want i want to display.

Comment: can u please provide me screen shot to both table?

Comment: how? can i send you the screenshot?